# Even Position Element

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am having difficulties solving the following math problem:

'Write a JS function that finds the elements at even positions in an array.
The input comes as an array of number elements.
The output must be displayed into element with id result like a text/string.'
Input : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
Output: 1 x 3 x 5 x 7 x 9

This is my code until now:

```
function evenPosition(arr) {

    let evenIndexes = [];
    let oddIndexes = [];

    for (let i = 1; i < arr.length + 1; i++) { 

        if (i % 2 !== 0) {
            oddIndexes.push(i)
        } else {
            evenIndexes.push(i)
        }

    }

}
evenPosition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I cannot sort the elements though as it is shown in the output... Can you guys please help?

Comment: you mean  need a result as string instead of array ? use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for array to string conversion

Comment: Write a JS function that finds the elements at even positions in an array. Do you want to create an array of elements at the even position of input array like this, input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], output:[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]?

Comment: Hi, guys. The output is supposed to print the values on the odd positions plus the values on the even ones in one array as strings. The even ones should be printed as x-s though. Here is the output that should be printed: 1 x 3 x 5 x 7 x 9

Comment: The sample has x's at the **odd** indexes. x's at the even indexes would be "x 2 x 3 x 5 ..." since indexes start at 0, so 1 is at zero (even index), 2 is at one (odd index), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array's join method to convert array into string with the  character's you want to join. Something like this.

```
function evenPosition(arr) {

    let evenArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 

        if (i % 2 === 0) { 
            evenArr.push(arr[i]);
        }

    }
    return evenArr.join(" x ");
}
console.log(evenPosition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

If you want to sort the array also then you can return something like this.

```
return evenArr.sort().join(" x ");
```

Comment: This will give correct result only for specific case where list values are always incrementing by 1.

Comment: There is no mention of sorting in the question.

Comment: this logic will give same out with 10th element like 'evenPosition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]'

Answer (score 1):

Is this you want?

```js
function evenPosition(arr) {
 
    let str = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 

        if (i % 2 !== 0) { 
            str += " x ";
        } else { 
            str += arr[i];
        }

    }
    return str;
}
console.log(evenPosition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

Comment: Hi! Yes! This is exactly it. The thing is that I am supposed to solve the math problem using array methods...

Comment: This replaces the values at **odd** indexes with x, not those at even indexes. `i % 2 !== 0` (or `!(i%2)`) is true at odd indexes.

Answer (score 1):

The example in the OP is incorrect. In the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, the odd values are at even indexes and the even values are at odd indexes. So the result of replacing the values at even indexes should be "x 2 x 4 x 6 x 8 x".

There are of course many ways to achieve the required outcome, e.g.

```js
// Return string with values at even indexes replaced by "x"
function evenPosition(arr) {
  let acc = 'x';
  return arr.slice(-(arr.length - 1)).reduce(
    (acc, curr, i) => acc += ' ' + (i%2? 'x' : curr), acc
  );
}

// Indexes start at 0, so even numbers are at odd indexes
let a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

console.log('Input: ' + a + ' Output: ' + evenPosition(a));

// Array with ellisions (sparse)
let b = [1,,,,5,6,,,9,10];

console.log('Input: ' + b + ' Output: ' + evenPosition(b));

// Using map and join
console.log('Input: ' + a + 
            ' Output: ' + (a.map((v, i) => i%2? v : 'x').join(' ')));
```